# How to load another view programmatically in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I need to load a view after an user has logged id.. To have the script determined if the username and password combined is correct i have the following code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"................."];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addPostValue:gebruikersnaam.text forKey:@"gebruikersnaam"];
    [request addPostValue:wachtwoord.text forKey:@"wachtwoord"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

    [request startSynchronous];

    NSString *toegang = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [request responseString]];

    int level = [toegang intValue];
    if(level == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inloggen mislukt!" message:@"Het inloggen met het opgegeven gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord is mislukt. Probeer het opnieuw" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Probeer Opnieuw" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } else {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

How do i trigger another view in the else{ statement? I need the view to be loaded when the user is logged in, and not when the app starts..

Comment: Why was there a `php` tag attached?

Comment: I'm sorry, the data that is begin received is from a PHP-page.. I also realised this has nothing to do with the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define programmatically your view, then you can use:

```
MyUIView* subview = [[[MyUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:subview];
```

If you need more help, please specify how you would like to define you `UIView`.

Comment: Actually i do not have an XIB file for the other view to be loaded. But only an .m and .h file.

Comment: That is perfectly fine. Then you instantiate your UIView and add it as a subview as shown above.